# Sonarqube 9.6.1 not starting - Windows10 cmd

Tags: sonarqube

I've set the environmental variable SONAR_JAVA_PATH.

It's taken in the SonarServiceWrapper.xml

```
  <!-- Path to the Java executable. To be replaced by SonarService.bat script -->
  <executable>D:\Programmes\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe</executable>

  <!-- DO NOT EDIT THE FOLLOWING SECTIONS -->
  <arguments>
    -Xms8m -Xmx32m
    -Djava.awt.headless=true
    --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
    -cp "..\..\..\lib\sonar-application-9.6.1.59531.jar" "org.sonar.application.App"
  </arguments>

  <id>SonarQube</id>
  <name>SonarQube</name>
  <description>SonarQube</description>

  <logpath>../../../logs</logpath>
  <log mode="none"/>

</service>
```

No error in the command line.

Only one log file SonarServiceWrapper.wrapper.log with this line :

```
2022-10-11 12:26:01,286 DEBUG - Starting WinSW in console mode
```

I've tried with jdk-11.0.2, jdk-13.0.2 and jdk-19 : same thing

Answer (score 2):

Add the following system environment, Ex:

```
SONAR_JAVA_PATH : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.17\bin\java.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

In StartSonar.bat, i've commented

```
REM call :check_if_sonar_is_running FAIL || goto:eof
```

Next, i use jdk-11.0.2

And sonarqube is up